# @mongodb Factors affecting write i/o operations

Tags: mongodb

I was doing some tests to figure out the performance of Replica Sets in our environment. The set up consists of 1 Primary and 1 Secondary in local Data Center and 1 Secondary in remote Data Center.

My record consists of 1 field of size 512 bytes. The numbers of inserts were 100,000 and 500,000.

During week 1 the inserts in primary were happening within the following time:
100,000 writes - 5 seconds
500,000 writes - 20 seconds

Week 2 -
100,000 writes - 14 seconds
500,000 writes - 66 seconds

I can't seem to figure what could have caused the rate to dip down so much. I have an oplog of size 1 GB and journaling enabled. I am not concerned about replication lag since there isn't much lag. There is no other i/o processes happening in the environments on which the mongodb is setup. I have also deleted files and restarted the machines but still I notice this dip.

Can anyone let me know what could be the cause?

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Are these physical or virtual machines?  (If virtual, you might have a "noisy neighbor".)  Are the hard disks local disks, or are they network mounted from a NAS or SAN?  (If network disks, write throughput might be affected by network traffic or I/O load from other hosts sharing the NAS/SAN.)

Comment: For testing, I am using VMs and the storage is network mounted from SAN. So I think you are correct. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are virtual machines, then you might have a "noisy neighbor".  If you're using NAS or SAN storage, then write throughput can be affected by network traffic or by I/O load for other hosts sharing the NAS or SAN.